# how to get the path of selected PDF/doc from file manager in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent

**I have written this code to open my Document manager and select any PDF/Doc file.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            Intent i = Intent.createChooser(intent, "File");
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

**When I select any Pdf/Doc file I am unable to get path of that select file.**

**I tried this code also but it give me null as output**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            String fileImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
            String type = intent.getType();

            Log.d("Hello", fileImagePath + "");
            if (uri != null) {
                String path = uri.toString();
                if (path.toLowerCase().startsWith("file://")) {
                    // Selected file/directory path is below
                    path = (new File(URI.create(path))).getAbsolutePath();
                    Log.d("Hel", path);
                }

            }
        } else
            Log.d("Hello", "Back from pick with cancel status");
    }
}




public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA );
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get instead? Where is that null? What do you consider the 'output'?

Comment: What is that Document manager you mentioned?

Comment: I expect path (Location ) of select PDF/DOC file from file manager(Document manager ) ( Link : )

Comment: I want output as **/storage/emulated/0/Download/HR Mantra Software pvt. Ltd (Responses) - Form Responses 1.pdf** . But by using this **String fileImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(uri)** , I get  **fileImagePath** as null

Comment: And by using **Uri uri = intent.getData();** I get  **content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1248** But I want location as I mention earlier in 1st comments.

Comment: Which android version?

Comment: Please try ES File Explorer.

Comment: Version Kitkat 4.4.2.. Look I understood what you are trying to say. But what if I install this application to another Android device which do not consist of ES file Explorer. I Hope you are getting me

Comment: Just give it a try. Many file pickers behave different. Try them all.

Comment: `file manager(Document manager ) (` Can yiou be mre exact please? Wich app exactly? Please adapt your code in such a way that you check the return value of getRealPathFromUri for null.

Comment: `But I want location as I mention earlier in 1st comments. `. Can you tell why? If you need an inputstream from that file you don't need it.

Comment: ok,I am making an Android application for my final year project ( Computer Engineering last sem ). In my application there is a mudule where I need to upload PDF/Doc file to the Server( for ex. userID and FileName) and In server Side I have managed everything in PHP and it is working fine.

Comment: Now I wrote that code, I have mentioned in my question, In order to upload any PDF/Doc file, I need to have path for selected file than only I can upload any file.

Comment: Now when I say Document Manager is nothing but our File manager, In erlier comments I have shared link of that how it looks like. I use SAMSUNG GRAND 2, so Whenever I press select file button it nevigates to me that File manager( Document Manager) and When I select any file that code doesn't give the exact file path this is the problem.

Comment: And if you have any alternate solution for this please let me know Thanks

Comment: Even if you want to upload the file using a file path you will mostly open a FileInputStream from that path. But you could as well open an input stream from the uri you have now.

Comment: Can you please share solution, I am facing same issue.

Comment: How was the problem solved

Comment: Has someone got the solution? i also want to get the pdf/doc/ppt file path in this format - /storage/emulated/0/Download/HR Mantra Software pvt. Ltd (Responses) - Form Responses 1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I did this... I hope I will help someone,
you have two option to open some file(pdf), if you want to use ES you have to do is parse your path of ES

```
 if (requestCode == 1) { 
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                if (uri != null) {
                    PATH_FILE = uri.toString();
                    if (PATH_FILE.substring(0, 1).equals("c")) { // ES
                        PATH_FILE = "file://" + PATH_FILE.substring(28,PATH_FILE.length());
                    }
                    if (PATH_FILE.toLowerCase().startsWith("file://")) {
                        PATH_FILE = (new File(URI.create(PATH_FILE))).getAbsolutePath();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what this means?

if (PATH_FILE.substring(0, 1).equals("c")) { // ES

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code for any sort of file :

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2007-2008 OpenIntents.org
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.yourpackage;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Peli
 * @author paulburke (ipaulpro)
 * @version 2013-12-11
 */
public class FileUtils {
    private FileUtils() {
    } //private constructor to enforce Singleton pattern

    /**
     * TAG for log messages.
     */
    static final String TAG = "FileUtils";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = true; // Set to true to enable logging

    public static final String MIME_TYPE_AUDIO = "audio/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_TEXT = "text/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_IMAGE = "image/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_VIDEO = "video/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_APP = "application/*";

    public static final String HIDDEN_PREFIX = ".";

    /**
     * Gets the extension of a file name, like ".png" or ".jpg".
     *
     * @param uri
     * @return Extension including the dot("."); "" if there is no extension;
     * null if uri was null.
     */
    public static String getExtension(String uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int dot = uri.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (dot >= 0) {
            return uri.substring(dot);
        } else {
            // No extension.
            return "";
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Whether the URI is a local one.
     */
    public static boolean isLocal(String url) {
        if (url != null && !url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return True if Uri is a MediaStore Uri.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isMediaUri(Uri uri) {
        return "media".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * Convert File into Uri.
     *
     * @param file
     * @return uri
     */
    public static Uri getUri(File file) {
        if (file != null) {
            return Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the path only (without file name).
     *
     * @param file
     * @return
     */
    public static File getPathWithoutFilename(File file) {
        if (file != null) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                // no file to be split off. Return everything
                return file;
            } else {
                String filename = file.getName();
                String filepath = file.getAbsolutePath();

                // Construct path without file name.
                String pathwithoutname = filepath.substring(0,
                        filepath.length() - filename.length());
                if (pathwithoutname.endsWith("/")) {
                    pathwithoutname = pathwithoutname.substring(0, pathwithoutname.length() - 1);
                }
                return new File(pathwithoutname);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return The MIME type for the given file.
     */
    public static String getMimeType(File file) {

        String extension = getExtension(file.getName());

        if (extension.length() > 0)
            return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.substring(1));

        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

    /**
     * @return The MIME type for the give Uri.
     */
    public static String getMimeType(Context context, Uri uri) {
        File file = new File(getPath(context, uri));
        return getMimeType(file);
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is {@link LocalStorageProvider}.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isLocalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return LocalStorageProvider.AUTHORITY.equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context       The context.
     * @param uri           The Uri to query.
     * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will quickGet the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.<br>
     * <br>
     * Callers should check whether the path is local before assuming it
     * represents a local file.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri     The Uri to query.
     * @author paulburke
     * @see #isLocal(String)
     * @see #getFile(Context, Uri)
     */
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG + " File -",
                    "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                            ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                            ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                            ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                            ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                            ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                            ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
            );
        // DocumentProvider
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // LocalStorageProvider
            if (isLocalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                // The path is the id
                return DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            }
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            else if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

//                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
//                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
//                }
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                try {
                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    Log.d(TAG, "getPath: id= " + id);
                    final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    List<String> segments = uri.getPathSegments();
                    if(segments.size() > 1) {
                        String rawPath = segments.get(1);
                        if(!rawPath.startsWith("/")){
                            return rawPath.substring(rawPath.indexOf("/"));
                        }else {
                            return rawPath;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Convert Uri into File, if possible.
     *
     * @return file A local file that the Uri was pointing to, or null if the
     * Uri is unsupported or pointed to a remote resource.
     * @author paulburke
     * @see #getPath(Context, Uri)
     */
    public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri != null) {
            String path = getPath(context, uri);
            if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
                return new File(path);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the file size in a human-readable string.
     *
     * @param size
     * @return
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static String getReadableFileSize(int size) {
        final int BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES = 1024;
        final DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
        final String KILOBYTES = " KB";
        final String MEGABYTES = " MB";
        final String GIGABYTES = " GB";
        float fileSize = 0;
        String suffix = KILOBYTES;

        if (size > BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES) {
            fileSize = size / BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES;
            if (fileSize > BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES) {
                fileSize = fileSize / BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES;
                if (fileSize > BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES) {
                    fileSize = fileSize / BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES;
                    suffix = GIGABYTES;
                } else {
                    suffix = MEGABYTES;
                }
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(dec.format(fileSize) + suffix);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to retrieve the thumbnail of given File from the MediaStore. This
     * should not be called on the UI thread.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param file
     * @return
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Context context, File file) {
        return getThumbnail(context, getUri(file), getMimeType(file));
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to retrieve the thumbnail of given Uri from the MediaStore. This
     * should not be called on the UI thread.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param uri
     * @return
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Context context, Uri uri) {
        return getThumbnail(context, uri, getMimeType(context, uri));
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to retrieve the thumbnail of given Uri from the MediaStore. This
     * should not be called on the UI thread.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param uri
     * @param mimeType
     * @return
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Context context, Uri uri, String mimeType) {
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to quickGet thumbnail");

        if (!isMediaUri(uri)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "You can only retrieve thumbnails for images and videos.");
            return null;
        }

        Bitmap bm = null;
        if (uri != null) {
            final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = resolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    final int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                    if (DEBUG)
                        Log.d(TAG, "Got thumb ID: " + id);

                    if (mimeType.contains("video")) {
                        bm = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                                resolver,
                                id,
                                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                                null);
                    } else if (mimeType.contains(FileUtils.MIME_TYPE_IMAGE)) {
                        bm = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                                resolver,
                                id,
                                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                                null);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    Log.e(TAG, "getThumbnail", e);
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return bm;
    }

    /**
     * File and folder comparator. TODO Expose sorting option method
     *
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static Comparator<File> sComparator = new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            // Sort alphabetically by lower case, which is much cleaner
            return f1.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(
                    f2.getName().toLowerCase());
        }
    };

    /**
     * File (not directories) filter.
     *
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static FileFilter sFileFilter = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            final String fileName = file.getName();
            // Return files only (not directories) and skip hidden files
            return file.isFile() && !fileName.startsWith(HIDDEN_PREFIX);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Folder (directories) filter.
     *
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static FileFilter sDirFilter = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            final String fileName = file.getName();
            // Return directories only and skip hidden directories
            return file.isDirectory() && !fileName.startsWith(HIDDEN_PREFIX);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Get the Intent for selecting content to be used in an Intent Chooser.
     *
     * @return The intent for opening a file with Intent.createChooser()
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static Intent createGetContentIntent() {
        // Implicitly allow the user to select a particular kind of data
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        // The MIME data type filter
        intent.setType("*/*");
        // Only return URIs that can be opened with ContentResolver
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        return intent;
    }
}
```